# Powershell error: The type initializer for 'System.Net.ServicePointManager' threw an exception

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell

Whenever I try to open Powershell, it just won't open. When I try to open it from the cmd, I get this error:

> The shell cannot be started. A failure occurred during initialization:
>   The type initializer for 'System.Net.ServicePointManager' threw an exception.

Things I have tried:

- opening with administrator
- sfc /scannow which showed no errors

The 32 bit version of powershell still works for some reason if that helps in any way.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT Thank you for the assistance, I followed your steps but the same error occurs.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT I tried everything you said and nothing worked. The only thing I couldn't do is look through Event Viewer because when I open it up I get this error `MMC cannot initialize the snap-in.` I wonder if this could be in any way related to the powershell error.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT I use Norton

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT After almost a month of searching, I narrowed this down to the Microsoft.NET folder in C:\Windows. I replaced this folder with a friend's Microsoft.NET folder who wasn't having the issue, and powershell suddenly works again.

Comment: Here's a tool here that may have helped too: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30135

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just dealt with this on a client computer. The problem was that the `machine.config` files for .NET Framework 4.x had both been corrupted (they had somehow become zero-length files).

Deleting the files is insufficient.

It worked to simply replace the zero length files with the code below, but I used the "known good" versions in order to ensure that there weren't any long-term side-effects.

This is the minimum required content for the `machine.config` files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration />
```

**Replacing** these two files with "known good" copies of `machine.config` from the same version resolved this for me and didn't leave me worrying that some unknown issue would crop up later.

After fixing or replacing the `machine.config` files a reboot is required.

The Windows `machine.config` file is located one of the following folders:

```
%Windows%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v{version}\CONFIG
%Windows%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v{version}\CONFIG
```

There may also be corrupted `machine.config` files for individual applications under their `*\mono\{version}` folders, though I would be much more hesitant to replace them without using a copy from the same application and application version on the same platform and CPU architecture.

In any case, on Windows, you can find the specific defective files by searching for zero-length files under the Windows folder named `machine.config`. This command will do that for you.

```
forfiles /P %windows% /S /M machine.config /C "cmd /c if @isdir==FALSE if @fsize EQU 0 echo @path"
```

Comment: Interesting, and good to know fix!!

Comment: I tried the minimum required version and it didn't work for me. I noticed I had a file named "machine.config.default". I replaced machine.config with that file and it worked!

Comment: Where is the machine.config file located? Seach finds several in the \Windows\WinSxS folder but the file can't be edited or deleted.

Comment: I updated the answer with tips for finding the defective machine.config files

Comment: Thanks for the update. However, though my problem appears to be the same, your solution doesn't solve it :( Typical Microsoft garbage...

Answer (score 0):

The issue is created due to powershell requiring access the .NET framework installed on microsoft. For me, it was installing GIT and using the windows default editor instead on MinTTy that caused the issue. .NET needs to be configured correctly for powershell to work. Luckily there is often a default config file that has the right settings to get you started.

So here is the working solution.

Locate both the following files:

```
%Windows%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v{version}\CONFIG\machine.config.default
%Windows%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v{version}\CONFIG\machine.config.default
```

Copy them **respectively** into:

```
%Windows%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v{version}\CONFIG\machine.config
%Windows%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v{version}\CONFIG\machine.config
```

Open PowerShell and voila!

NOTE: I did not even need to reboot for powershell to work.